# set springboot starting check redis,database,mq

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I want set springboot starting check redis,database,mq connection

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        return new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
    }
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        StringRedisTemplate template = new StringRedisTemplate(factory);
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        om.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(om);
        template.setValueSerializer( jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
}
```

> I WANT SET SPRINGBOOT STARTING CHECK REDIS CONNECTION

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set redis connection using application.properties. Please add flowing properties to application.properties

```
spring.redis.database=0 # Database index used by the connection factory.
spring.redis.url= # Connection URL, will override host, port and password (user will be ignored), e.g. redis://user:password@example.com:6379
spring.redis.host=localhost # Redis server host.
spring.redis.password= # Login password of the redis server.
```

Please refer spring documentation for more information.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html